# What is wrong when I call this array from a variable?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, variables

I have been do it a template page for Wordpress Theme. In it, have to filter some tags from an user field.

But for test, I do it that:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$contexto = get_user_meta($user_id, 'contexto', true);
$contexto = '"' . $contexto . '"';
$array = array (
    "Buscando mi nicho​" => "buscando-mi-nicho",
    "Montando mi blog" => "montando-mi-plataforma",
    "Buscando lectores" => "buscando-lectores",
    "Construyendo mi lista de correo​" => "construyendo-mi-lista-de-correo",
    "Vendiendo mi primer producto/servicio​" => "vendiendo-mi-primer-productoservicio",
    "Buscando más clientes​​​" => "escalar-ventas",
    "A punto de dar el gran salto (para vivir de mi blog)​" => "a-punto-de-dar-el-gran-salto-para-vivir-de-mi-blog",
    "Ya soy Knowmada Full Time​" => "ya-soy-knowmada-full-time"
    );
    $etiqueta = $array[$contexto];
$user_first = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true );
echo '<p>Hola '. $user_first . '.  Queremos ayudarte a progresar, y tu etapa actual es <strong>' . $contexto . '</strong>,  por eso, te recomendamos los siguientes contenidos con la etiqueta <b>' . $etiqueta . '</b></p>';
```

And I get:

> Hola Javier. Queremos ayudarte a progresar, y tu etapa actual es **"Montando mi blog"**, por eso, te recomendamos los siguientes contenidos con la etiqueta

You can see, that I don't get the variable `$etiqueta`.

If I put, for example:

```
$etiqueta = $array["Montando mi blog"];
```

I get:

> Hola Javier. Queremos ayudarte a progresar, y tu etapa actual es "Montando mi blog", por eso, te recomendamos los siguientes contenidos con la etiqueta montando-mi-plataforma

So I get `$etiqueta`.

What is wrong whit:

```
    $etiqueta = $array[$contexto];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the keys in your array to not have the double quotes ("). Remove the line:

```
$contexto = '"' . $contexto . '"';
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks very much! It's Work. Also have a problem with some hidden characters.